# Convert Date format in SQLite Database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite Database and I mistakenly loaded a lot of data with mismatching date formats. There are dates formatted as: MM/DD/YYYY and dates formatted as: DD-Month Abbr. - YY.

I would really like them all to be YYYYMMDD. Is there a way to reformat all of the dates to match the preferred format?

Thanks!

Comment: SQLite does not support formatting functions for non ISO dates. Post sample data of your dates that cover all cases.

Comment: Can you explicitly list each and every format that you've used?  You can then use where clauses such as `LIKE '__/__/____'` to find rows of one format and `LIKE '__-___-__'` to find rows of another format. Then you can write separate translation code for each format, and fix rows of each format, one format at a time. But, first, you need to be explicit about All the formats you need to translate. What you don't want to accidentally do is write a where clause that matches more than one input format, and mangle a row thinking it's formatted one way, but is actually formatted a different way.

Comment: Also, your target format should be one supported by Sqlite's functions.  That does Not include `YYYYMMDD`, you should be including the `-` delimiter...  https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#time_values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only 2 different date formats, you can reformat them by parsing differenly. Follow @MatBailie's suggestion and use a format supported by Sqlite's functions, i used `YYYY-MM-DD`

I decoded `MM/DD/YYYY` format by finding parts of a date. And than, i decoded `DD-Month Abbr. - YY` format separately for each Month.

For `MM/DD/YYYY` format

```
update dates set theDate = substr(theDate, 7, 4 ) 
                        || '-' || substr(theDate, 1, 2 ) || '-'
                        || substr(theDate, 4, 2 )
where instr(theDate, '/') > 0;
```

For `DD-Month Abbr. - YY` format

```
update dates set theDate = substr(theDate, 8, 4 ) 
                        || '-01-'
                        || substr(theDate, 1, 2 )
where instr(theDate, '-Jan-') > 0;                         

update dates set theDate = substr(theDate, 8, 4 ) 
                        || '-02-'
                        || substr(theDate, 1, 2 )
where instr(theDate, '-Feb-') > 0;  

update dates set theDate = substr(theDate, 8, 4 ) 
                        || '-03-'
                        || substr(theDate, 1, 2 )
where instr(theDate, '-Mar-') > 0;  

update dates set theDate = substr(theDate, 8, 4 ) 
                        || '-04-'
                        || substr(theDate, 1, 2 )
where instr(theDate, '-Apr-') > 0;  

update dates set theDate = substr(theDate, 8, 4 ) 
                        || '-05-'
                        || substr(theDate, 1, 2 )
where instr(theDate, '-May-') > 0; 

update dates set theDate = substr(theDate, 9, 4 ) 
                        || '-06-'
                        || substr(theDate, 1, 2 )
where instr(theDate, '-June-') > 0; 

update dates set theDate = substr(theDate, 9, 4 ) 
                        || '-07-'
                        || substr(theDate, 1, 2 )
where instr(theDate, '-July-') > 0; 

update dates set theDate = substr(theDate, 8, 4 ) 
                        || '-08-'
                        || substr(theDate, 1, 2 )
where instr(theDate, '-Aug-') > 0; 

update dates set theDate = substr(theDate, 9, 4 ) 
                        || '-09-'
                        || substr(theDate, 1, 2 )
where instr(theDate, '-Sept-') > 0; 

update dates set theDate = substr(theDate, 8, 4 ) 
                        || '-10-'
                        || substr(theDate, 1, 2 )
where instr(theDate, '-Oct-') > 0; 

update dates set theDate = substr(theDate, 8, 4 ) 
                        || '-11-'
                        || substr(theDate, 1, 2 )
where instr(theDate, '-Nov-') > 0; 

update dates set theDate = substr(theDate, 8, 4 ) 
                        || '-12-'
                        || substr(theDate, 1, 2 )
where instr(theDate, '-Dec-') > 0;
```

[Tested on sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f71e5/1)

Comment: Thank you! I think this will be the ticket. The database has too many records to reload the data manually.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SQLite does not have a date data type, if reloading the data is really that much of an effort you could use REPLACE to replace the month using a case statement for each month:

```
 CASE WHEN MONTH = 'Jan' THEN REPLACE('Jan', 'Jan', '01') 
 WHEN MONTH = 'Feb' THEN REPLACE('Feb', 'Feb', '02') 
 WHEN MONTH = 'Mar' THEN REPLACE('Mar', 'Mar', '03') END
```

Then you could substring the first 2 characters, middle 2, and last 2 to move them into any format you want.